# Force new line between two functions using swiftlint

Tags: ios, swiftlint

I have added custom_rule for forcing single line space between two functions. Below is my custom rule. But it is not showing warning. Anyone having idea of this?

```
custom_rules:
        comma_space_rule:
                include: "*.swift"
                regex: '([}]\nfunc\s\w+(\(.*\))\s[{])'
                name: "Single line space between functions"
                message: "Single line space violation: Expected single whitespace between functions"
                severity: warning
```

Comment: did you found a solution to this @Dharani ?

Comment: Changing the regex to `'([}]\n[[:blank:]]*func\s\w+(\(.*\))\s[{])'` worked for me.
This regex also accounts for the empty space before the word `func`